# wvdial can't retrieve modem response, terminal programs communicate without problems

Tags: linux, debian, serial-port, raspbian, wvdial

I'm trying to make a GPRS connection with a SIM800L and a PL2303 USB-Serial cable.

If I *screen* or *minicom* the modem (at 115200 8N1) I get an immediate response from the modem and I even after setting up the PDP and GPRS context I can successfully ping google servers through AT commands. I'm also able to initiate a PPP connection through `AT+CGDATA="PPP"` or `ATDT*99***1#`.

But with *wvdial* the modem won't respond

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot set information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATZ
--> Modem not responding.
```

If I do a `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` and run *wvdial* at the same time
I get this:

```
ATZ0
OK

OK

OK
```

**After *wvdial* has ended** the command and the first `OK` appears, one second later the two `OK` will appear. Also I would like to note that `ATZ` and `ATQ0` commands became **overlapped**.

I might be hijacking the output through *cat* and that might be the reason but the behaviour of *wvdial* is the same with or without *cat*.

This is my */etc/wvdial.conf*

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 115200
Phone = *99***1#
Username = webgprs
Password = webgprs2002
New PPPD = yes
```

`Modem Type = Analog Modem` doesn't make any difference.
If I put some `Init#` parameters they won't get any response either.
The overlapping of commands will happen with the `Init#` commands too.

Getting abstraction layers out as noted in [3G and GPRS modems with pppd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd) resulting in using only *pppd* didn't work either. What's clear is that communication with the serial port by system process aren't being held, only through serial port clients.

*sakis3g* communicates successfully with the modem but is unable to bring up an interface.

```
[13751] [11:45:56] Connection command that will be used is: /usr/bin/setsid /usr/sbin/pppd /dev/ttyUSB0 460800 modem crtscts -detach defaultroute dump noipdefault usepeerdns usehostname ktune logfd 2 noauth name sakis3g lock maxfail 3 connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /tmp/pppd.tmp.13751" user "webgprs" password "webgprs2002"
[13751] [11:45:56] Verbosing: 28% Initializing modem
[13751] [11:45:56] Using default INITIALIZE.
[13751] [11:45:56] Command "INITIALIZE" refers to AT commands: ATZ OK 'AT&F' OK 'ATQ0 V1 E1' OK 'AT&D2 &C1' OK AT+FCLASS=0 OK ATS0=0 OK 'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.itelcel.com"' OK
[13751] [11:45:56] Will send INITIALIZE commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK ATZ OK 'AT&F' OK 'ATQ0 V1 E1' OK 'AT&D2 &C1' OK AT+FCLASS=0 OK ATS0=0 OK 'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.itelcel.com"' OK '\pAT' OK
[13751] [11:45:57] We are root already. Proceeding.
[13751] [11:45:57] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[13751] [11:45:58] Got response from tty:
AT
OK
ATZ
OK
AT&F
OK
ATQ0 V1 E1
OK
AT&D2 &C1
OK
AT+FCLASS=0
ERROR
[13751] [11:45:58] Unknown command "STAGE7".
[13751] [11:45:58] Unknown command "STAGE8".
[13751] [11:45:58] We are root already. Proceeding.
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13751] [11:45:58] Will now run command: \'/bin/rm -f "/tmp/sakis3g.3gnet"\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13751] [11:45:58] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13751] [11:45:58] We are root already. Proceeding.
[13751] [11:45:58] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[13751] [11:45:58] Verbosing: 35% Connecting
[13751] [11:45:58] PID 15625 is still running.
[13751] [11:45:59] Located "netstat" within PATH (/bin/netstat).
[13751] [11:45:59] Waiting for interface to go up (0 seconds passed).
[13751] [11:46:00] PID 15625 is still running.
[13751] [11:46:00] Waiting for interface to go up (1 seconds passed).
[13751] [11:46:01] PID 15625 is still running.
[13751] [11:46:01] Waiting for interface to go up (2 seconds passed).
... (truncated) ...
[13751] [11:46:56] Waiting for interface to go up (20 seconds passed).
[13751] [11:46:57] Giving up waiting for connection to occur.
[13751] [11:46:57] PID 16179 is still running.
[13751] [11:46:58] PID 16179 is not running any more.
[13751] [11:46:58] PID 16179 is not running any more.
[13751] [11:46:58] Failed to connect.
[13751] [11:46:58] Error: Failed to connect.
[13751] [11:46:58] Aborting execution chain due to actor "connect" returning 95.
```

The result it's the same even if I manually set up the PDP context and set the modem in a GPRS active context

```
AT+CIPSTATUS
IP STATUS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading sakis3g logs and source I notice that using `nocrtscts` on ppp options with this PL2303 USB Serial converter is mandatory.
Also, the SIM800L doesn't support `AT+FCLASS` command and makes the chat script fail so I had to removed it.

Using the chat script from [3G and GPRS modems with pppd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd) I changed the line:

```
'OK' 'ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0'
```

to

```
'OK' 'ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2'
```

The `AT+FCLASS` is used to select the Fax Mode. If your GSM module doesn't even support this mode (or defaults to 0 -- data mode) then it seems safe to leave that part out the chat script.

Answer (score 1):

I have traced this problem to RTS/CTS flow control which libwvstreams (and thus wvdial) use by default but my tiny USB serial dongle does not support.

You can use [my patch on GitHub](https://github.com/aib/wvdial/commit/e3bf0b58364b43586647be6431a8a7b5bd75444e) or fix it in hardware. If your dongle has RTS and CTS pins, for example (and your modem doesn't), you can connect them to eachother.